# Does client automatically encrypts when using transport security?

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

While inspecting traffic through fiddler, I noticed that the calls to my online server were not encrypted, the data sent was easily readable in the soap body even though the call was to https address(SSL is already installed for the domain). I am using transport security with client authentication none. Is it default behavior?, I was under the impression that the data passes to the server on SSL is encrypted too and can't be viewed.

Comment: If you set transport level security in the configuration and set up a certificate to be used, I suppose it should be ancrypted. Take a look here for some related information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729789.aspx.

Comment: The domain has a certificate installed. I do not authenticate the client though.

Comment: Which type of binding do you use? `BasicHttpsBinding`, `WsHttpBinding` or a different one? Take a look at a link in my previous comment as it seems to be related to your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you've specified transport security, SSL will be used. I'd suggest 2 possibilities:

1. You've configured Fiddler to view SSL-secured connections (this is possible but not recommended in most cases).
2. You're not referencing the binding that you think you're referencing.

Comment: Actually, there are two WCF services running on the domain, both have common configuration but different endpoints and addresses. The problem is the second one seems to be not working correct, when I access it using testclient I see that the binding its using is basic while I have set it to ws.

Comment: Since you have confirmed that the second service doesn't use the expected binding, doesn't that explain why it's not using SSL?